# Methods selection with Overloading and Overriding

Tags: java, overloading

**How the JVM chooses which method to execute?**

Is it true that the choosing process is divided into 2 parts. First while compiling the JVM looks for a candidate method to execute. It selects the required signature into the declared object class (not the effective one). Once it selected the candidate signature, it starts looking for it in the hierarchy starting from the **effective** class of the object.
**Is this correct?**

One more questions:

Here is a classes hierarchy and related methods:

```
- Class A: +f(short x): int; +f(String x): int;
- Class B extends A: +f(int x): int; +f(String x): int;
- Class C extends A: +f(double x): int; +f(byte x): int;
- Class D extends C: +f(byte x): int; +f(short x): int;
- Class E extends C: +f(char x): int; +f(int x): int;
```

So:

- A is superclass for B and C
- B is subclass of A
- C is subclass of A
- C is superclass for D and E
- D and E are C subclasses

All of these classes have only one method called "f" with mentioned signatures.

I now declare following objects:

```
A a = new D();
B b = new B();
C c = new E();
```

**1. Why the method call a.f(3) can't be handled and returns an error?**

If what i mentioned before is correct this is what should happen:

The JVM looks into Class A for a method with signature f(int x) or any compatible signature (with casting). It finds method f(short x) which should be compatible, right? Then it looks for this very exact signature into Class D, and it finds it executing the D: f(short x). According to my book this isn't correct, why? It can be because short isn't actually a promotion for int and therefore the JVM doesn't consider f(short x) suitable for the call? And therefore won't find any f method compatible and will return an error.

I checked on Google and on any other resource i could find (also on Stackoverflow) but all were very obvious and not enough detailed answers, therefore i thought could be a good thing to ask, i hope it will turn our that the answer will be useful for future students fighting with overloading and overridding :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole process is described in the Java Language Specification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is definetely the documentation i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only two methods that could be called are:

Class A: `+f(short x): int; +f(String x): int;`

In order for the cast to be valid we need to implicitly cast the integer 3 to either a short or a string.

But you cannot implicitly convert the integer 3 to the smaller size short.  And of course it can't be implicitly cast to a string so it can't be handled.

Edit:

Because you put an instance of class D into the A container, the instance a only knows about A methods.  You have to cast the instance of a to D in order to call D's methods which then would enable you to implicitly cast the int 3 to a double and call the `f(double)` method.

Comment: Well, thanks for the reply to my second question. Regarding the fact that the only two methods that could be called are the ones from A, i'm not entirely sure i got what you meant.

Answer (score -2):

With regards to your second question (why the method call errors)

You've put yourself in a position where you've got four complex things you need to worry about here: overloading, overriding, datatype conversion and (potentially) autoboxing.

The one that's most interesting may actually be conversion. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Due to inheritance rules, the object a has the following operations:

```
 f(byte) (from D)
 f(short) (from D)
 f(double) (from C)
 f(String) (from A)
```

But the thing is, calling this function with the value 3 *really* means "an integer constant of 3."  You can't implicitly cast an integer to a byte or a string, as this is a narrowing conversion. However, you *can* implicitly cast an integer to a double or a float.

So I'd expect a.f(3) to evaluate f(double) from C.

Comment: This is not true, a does not know that its an instance of D therefore without casting you cannot access any other methods that are not in A and its parents.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your quick and clear reply. Unfortunately i can assure you that it won't eval to C: f(double) -actually, it won't eval at all returning an error- because as the a object is from class A and during compiling JVM will look for an elegible signature in A, not in C. As in A there are no elegible signatures, it will simply return an error. At least this is what i suspect. My main doubt is: can it be eval using the f(short x) in A? Someone has replied that: No, you can't.